# Action view error in Ruby on Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

I am trying to code a weekly digest as the ones used by quora or medium.

I want to sent a weekly selection of promos to a verified list of suscribers. To do that, I plan to create the mailer, and a rake task that I will run weekly.

I keep getting an error about the template of @promos, which I have check to be in place.

**Task.rake**

```
desc 'send digest email'
task send_weekly_email: :environment  do

  @promociones = Promo.where("validez <= ?", Time.zone.now).order("created_at DESC")
  @suscriptors = Suscriptor.where(email_confirmation: true)

  @suscriptors.each do |suscriptor|
      WeeklyDigestMailer.weekly_promos(suscriptor, @promociones).deliver_now
  end
end
```

**WeeklyDigestMailer**

```
class WeeklyDigestMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => "info@adeter.org"
  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.weekly_digest_mailer.weekly_promos.subject
  #
  def weekly_promos(suscriptor, promos)
      @promos = promos
      mail(:to => "<#{suscriptor.email}>", :subject => "Mercadillo digital semanal de Guia#{ENV['CURRENT_CITY_CAP']}.es")
  end
end
```

**weekly_promos.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <% @promos.each do |promo| %>

      <% link_to promo_url do %>

      <p><h2><%= promo.title %></h2></p>
      <p><%= promo.texto %></p>
      <p><%= promo.imgpromo %></p>
      <p>hasta: <span><%= promo.validez %></span> </p> -->

     <% end %>

  <% end %>
</p>
```

Rake::Task['send_weekly_email'].execute
**Console output**

```
  Suscriptor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "suscriptors".* FROM "suscriptors" WHERE "suscriptors"."email_confirmation" = $1  [["email_confirmation", "t"]]
  Rendering weekly_digest_mailer/weekly_promos.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Promo Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "promos".* FROM "promos" WHERE (validez <= '2018-12-19 22:37:51.784767') ORDER BY "promos"."created_at" DESC, created_at DESC
  Rendered weekly_digest_mailer/weekly_promos.html.erb within layouts/mailer (15.4ms)
WeeklyDigestMailer#weekly_promos: processed outbound mail in 25.4ms
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"promos"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the error comes from `link_to promo_url`, what's `promo_url` ?, shouldn't that be `promo.url` ?

Comment: You need to do `link_to promo_url(promo)`. That's a member route so it requires an `:id`, and Rails can't provide the id without an object to tell it what id to use.

Comment: Guys, you both were right. I added no parameters. It is specifically moveson's answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make this an answer to mark as answered

Comment: @JuanseCora I submitted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `link_to promo_url(promo)`. The helper method `promo_url` is a member route, so it requires an `:id`, and Rails can't provide the id without an object to tell it what id to use.